# Laravel route not showing as HTTPS in form?

Tags: laravel-4

I created a form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'cart.add')) }}
```

I have this in my routes.php file:

```
Route::post( 'cart/add',  array('https' => true, 'uses' => 'CartController@addToCart', 'as' => 'cart.add'));
```

Yet, the resulting HTML is:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/cart/add" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

I was expecting:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://localhost/cart/add" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

because the route is defined as needing HTTPS.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that this:

```
Route::post( 'cart/add',  array('https' => true, 'uses' => 'CartController@addToCart', 'as' => 'cart.add'));
```

Had to be this:

```
Route::post( 'cart/add',  array('https', 'uses' => 'CartController@addToCart', 'as' => 'cart.add'));
```